# How to delete a directive which has an isolated scope from the DOM properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a directive with an isolated scope.

How can I remove the directive from the DOM properly? I read that I have to remove the element from the DOM but before I also have to destroy the scope of the directive.

What is the best practice to destroy the scope of the directive from outside as I normally have to access to it as it is isolated?

Comment: well, you can just let angular do the work for you and make the directive conditional with an ng-if

Comment: @SoluableNonagon conditional `ng-if` will not be a good solution which will again create a new scope

Comment: @Flo if u got solution of this please share it...

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has no proper support to destroy child/isolated scopes. I created a custom function to force call the $destroy function:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    // destroy function for child/isolated scopes, because angular will not clean this up
    // see: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/12701/commits/f582cd5eb97ea54bc1183d3dddfd86097d86656a
    $rootScope.constructor.prototype.$destroyChild = function () {
        if (this.$destroy !== angular.noop) {
            this.$$destroyed = false;
            this.$broadcast = angular.noop; // prevent broadcast in $destroy()
            this.$destroy();
        }
    };
}]);
```

In your directive just do this:

```
element.on('$destroy', function () {
    // TODO: cleanup non-Angular components (such as jQuery)

    scope.$destroyChild(); // destroy child scope when element is destroyed on DOM
});

scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    // TODO: cleanup timers ($timeout.cancel( ... )), custom angular components created dynamic in directive etc.
});
```

Explanation: Angular calls $destroy on the parent scope. This broadcast $destroy to all child scopes. Afterwards the element gets destroyed from the DOM. Here we call the new $destroyChild() function in order to destroy the child scope (with all watches and angular stuff).

Disclaimer: This is still a workaround, but it should work. A better solution is to use the typescript Angular version.